# Need safe way to interpret and execute user defined logic on the server in a web environment

Tags: c#, javascript, sandbox

I have c# .Net MVC 5.1 web app that is driven by a data format where users can define logic in Xml.

When the user triggers a POST from the client the JSON model will be posted to the server and the Test will then be interpreted and evaluated using the json model.

```
var Model = {
    Data: {
        IsWeekday: true
    }
}
```

I was thinking about interpreting and executing this as javascript on the server.
Can anyone recommend a safe way of achieving this in a sandbox that wont allow any malicious code access to the server?

[This post on clearscript](http://clearscript.codeplex.com/discussions/435636) seems to be saying that it is safe if you dont expose any host objects and you remove the ActiveXObject

Comment: Host the web app in an isolated VM for maximum segregation

Answer (score 0):

If i do not misunderstood nothing, there should be a lot of google's V8 porting for the Net framework (eg : https://v8dotnet.codeplex.com/).
So you could load which porting you prefer and execute the javascript inside the V8 sandbox.